# How to add event handlers to dynamically created buttons in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I used AJAX to dynamically create the HTML but I've encountered a problem

```
<script>
    function page_loaded(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "get_data_dashboard.php",
            success: function(data){
                var markers = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
                    var m = markers[i];
                    var markerHTML = "<div class='marker'>" +
                        "<span id='naziv'>Naziv zahtjeva: " + m.naziv + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<span id='ulica'>Ulica: " + m.ulica + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<p id='opis'>Opis:</br>" + m.opis + "</p></br>" + 
                        "<span id='email'>Email: " + m.email + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<img id='slika' src='" + m.link_slike + "' />" + "</br>" + 
                        "<textarea rows='5' cols='30' maxlength='500' id='t" + m.marker_id + "' placeholder='Komentar'>" + "</textarea></br>"
                        + "<div class='buttons'><a href='odobri_prijavu.php?id=" + m.marker_id + "'>Odobri</a>" +
                            "<a href='izbrisi_prijavu.php?id=" + m.marker_id + "'>Izbriši</a>"  + "</div>"  + 
                        "</div><hr>";

                    $('#content').append(markerHTML);
                }

            }
        })



    }
    $(document).ready(page_loaded());

</script>
```

I tried to use buttons first instead of anchor tags but I couldn't figure how to add event handlers to dynamically created buttons that will post a request via AJAX to some php script with the proper id as the value and the value of the textarea. So I used the anchor tag and I was able to send the id, but I can't send the value of the textarea because I don't know how to reference it and even if I referenced it, it will be NULL because its value is set to the anchor tag at the very beginning and I want to type in text in the textarea.

Comment: You probably want to use event delegation.

Comment: when assigning the id to your tag give the textarea the same id as the button and append 'txtArea' to it. add an onclick (or what ever event your need) on the buttons and give it a function that will take the id of the button. that way u'll know how to get the button and the textarea associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    function page_loaded(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "get_data_dashboard.php",
            success: function(data){
                var markers = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
                    var m = markers[i];
                    var markerHTML = "<div class='marker'>" +
                        "<span id='naziv'>Naziv zahtjeva: " + m.naziv + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<span id='ulica'>Ulica: " + m.ulica + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<p id='opis'>Opis:</br>" + m.opis + "</p></br>" + 
                        "<span id='email'>Email: " + m.email + "</span></br>" + 
                        "<img id='slika' src='" + m.link_slike + "' />" + "</br>" + 
                        "<textarea rows='5' cols='30' maxlength='500' id='t" + m.marker_id + "' placeholder='Komentar'>" + "</textarea></br>"
                        + "<div class='buttons'><a href='odobri_prijavu.php?id=" + m.marker_id + "' onclick="clickHandler('"+m.marker_id+"')">Odobri</a>" +
                            "<a href='izbrisi_prijavu.php?id=" + m.marker_id + "'>Izbriši</a>"  + "</div>"  + 
                        "</div><hr>";

                    $('#content').append(markerHTML);
                }

            }
        })



    }
    $(document).ready(page_loaded());
    function clickHandler(id){
      $('#'+id) // selects the button
      $('#t'+id) // selects the text area
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I just replaced the anchor tags again with buttons and it works perfectly :D

Answer (score 3):

Instead of listening to individual "elements", you can actually listen to a parent of a specific element (You'll need to supply another parameter to on()). A popular pattern is to listen to "body" (because body is a parent to all, technically), but any non-dynamic parent element will work! Here's an example:

```
//notice the second parameter supplied
$("body").on("click", ".my-dynamic-element", function(e){
    //awesome code that makes the world a better place goes here
    //this code triggers when .my-dynamic-element is clicked, wootz
});
```

Comment: Love that comment :D. I will try it and report back :D

Comment: let us know! otherwise post your full code so we can further debug.

Comment: This is a good comment. What would also make the code 'smarter' is to use a template. Try looking into 'script type="x-template"'... example: `<script id="x" type="x-template" src="path_to_file"></script>`.
It's not really a standard I believe, but the script can be used because the browser does not parse it. Then you can later use jquery to parse the whole string of the script. It's a whole lot less messy than string concatenation to be able to use a plain text file. After using `var template = $('#x').html()`, do the replacements as follows: `template.find('.whatever').text(replacement);`

Answer (score 2):

Event delegation is your friend.

I don`t see any actions that actually do event handling, but a simple solution would be something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.your-button-class', function(){
 // do your thing
});
```

Comment: They don't because I removed the buttons and replaced them with anchor tags. I will replace the anchor tags now with the buttons and try Event delegation.

Comment: oh I saw I wasn`t the first, but honestly button or anchor tags make no difference whatsoever, you can use whatever you want.